# MonoGame hosted in a control/form

Tags: c#, monogame, tools, control

I would very much like to host my monogame window inside a Form so that I can take advantage of the nice gui elements in the C# framework when creating a simple level editor. I have looked online, but I am unable to find any working examples on how to do it. What is the state of this? Is it possible? I am using window 8.

Regards,

Comment: You might want to have a look here: https://github.com/jaquadro/MonoGame-WinFormsControls. It seems possible to do with little tricks.

Comment: I have had a look at it before posting, but I am unable to get it to work.
First I changed the assembly from windows phone to windows 8, but then nothing in the draw call seemed to make a difference (changing the background colour did not change anything for example) and after trying to instal openTK (only had mongame installed before) I got an error saying platform not supported.

Comment: I am far from being a Mono or C# expert, so I will not post any answer as I cannot help you much. I just found that link with a quick google search. I hope a MonoGame and C# expert will answer you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example of Monogame + WPF interop:
http://panthernet.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/21-monogame-wpf-interop-application/

Comment: Link is dead...